# iptables routing traffic from1 pc to another and then out to specific internet IP

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have a server (10.10.10.2) that cant access the internet and has an app on it that needs to access a service on public IP w.x.y.z
Another server (10.10.10.3) that does have internet access can connect to public IP w.x.y.z

10.10.10.2 and 10.10.10.3 are on the same internal network
How would I get 10.10.10.2 to connect to w.x.y.z via 10.10.10.3
I am trying with iptables but getting nowhere.

Thanx in adv

Answer (score 0):

Tell `10.10.10.2` to route packets for `w.x.y.z` to `10.10.10.3`:

```
route add -host w.x.y.z gw 10.10.10.3
```

Then use SNAT on 10.10.10.3 by doing

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --protocol tcp \
  --source 10.10.10.2 --destination w.x.y.z \
  --jump SNAT --to 10.10.10.3
```